# C# Linq - GroupBy - select most common/frequent entry details from windows event log

Tags: c#, windows, linq, visual-studio-2019, event-log

Im a C# newbie but has managed to successfully query the windows event log using Linq, returning the number of system errors for the last hour for example.

However, I would also like to filter out which of these events are most common/frequent - and select the newest one. And from there extract event log ID, providername, TimeCreated, count/frequency and message.
(This is going to be used to log to a simple text-file. Expected output:

2021-04-23 07:00:00 - 08:00:00 COMPUTERNAME System Error 23 Warning 11 Information 78 Application Error 0 Warning 3 Information 7 Security_Count 411

*Most common type of error:
2021-04-23 07:00:00 - 08:00:00 COMPUTERNAME System Error Top Count:11 EventID:7 Source/ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-NTFS Message: bla bla bla*

)

Writing the log file works fine. What I cant figure out is how the filter out these data using Linq

C# code:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-3600000);
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-1);

var evtlogresult = entries.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                           .Where(

                           x => (

                               x.TimeWritten >= start
                               && x.TimeWritten <= end
                               && x.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error

                           ))
                           .Select(

                           x => (
                                               x.EventID,
                                               x.EntryType,
                                               x.Source,
                                               x.Message,
                                               x.TimeWritten,
                                               x.MachineName,
                                               x.Site,
                                               x.UserName

                       )).ToList();
```

Ive done this in PowerShell, using group-object, and I guess Linq-groupBy is kind of the same thing.

PowerShell equivalence:

```
$top_count = $evtlogresult | Group-Object EventID | 
    sort-object count -descending |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty count -first 1
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions? Thanks.